# Randomizing numbers in a for loop

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

How do I randomize the numbers in a for loop in python 2.7.5?  The for loop looks like this:
    for i in[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]:
I already tried using the import random thing, maybe I wasn't using it right, but I don't know.

Comment: Also, googling for "python list in random order" gives lots of links to answers immediately. https://www.google.com.au/#q=python+list+in+random+order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

random.shuffle(lst)

for e in lst:
    # do your stuff
```